# SharePoint search Service Automatically start After "Disable"

Tags: search, service, searchserviceapplication

I do not want Search functionality in my SharePoint Server. Therefore I wanted to STOP the Search Service.

But, when I disable and Stop the Search Service, it automatically start after time of interval. Any clues why it starts automatically even after stopping?

Answer (score 2):

Try using PowerShell commend

> Stop-SPServiceInstance -Identity

Example

> Stop-SPServiceInstance 67877d63-bff4-4521-867a-ef4979ba07ce

Where  is the GUID of the service. If you do not know the service GUID, you can retrieve a list of all services in the farm together with their GUIDs by using the **Get-SPServiceInstance** cmdlet.

---

Or if this not works then use following comment in PowerShell

> Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Local | Stop-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance

Answer (score -1):

Go to service property. Change logon with wrong user password. Save it with disabled type. It will not start automatically.

Comment: But, I Think It's not a proper way, because It continuously throw error in my event log @viraj

Comment: At first start search service from local services. Pause all crawling from Central admin >> Manage Service Application >> Search Service Application >> Content Sources. Now again disable search service from local services and check it.

Comment: Wrong way to stop search service.